# Should a view-model be coupled to a view or to a model?

Tags: mvvm

That is, let's say I have a model that's used in several views. Should I create a single view model to represent it across all those views, or should I create a separate view model for each view that uses the model?

Comment: I’ve always hated the name view-model. Tells you where it belongs but not what it’s for.

Answer (score -1):

With classic OOP find the things that are common across all these views and create a base model that these use and extend.

But composition is a better deign pattern in my opinion. Create modules (ViewModel and view) then create combinations of these to create your variations.

Answer (score -1):

If you created separate view models for each view, would they end up containing exactly the same code? In that case use a single class. Would they contain different code? Then use separate classes. More generally, if you find yourself copy-pasting the same code into multiple files, you are probably doing something wrong.

A view model should not be coupled to the view, so there is nothing wrong with having multiple views using the same view model.